# Good software to generate SQL from ER diagram?

Tags: sql, database

I am creating a database and I need to create some tables.

I would like to know which software do you use or recommend (preferably free) to generate SQL code from ER diagram.

Comment: What tool are you using for the ER diagram?  Most tools generate the SQL directly.

Comment: Are you using a specific RDMBS (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc)?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I am looking for a tool. Not using any tool now, just SQL code from scratch.

Comment: @RQDQ: I am working with MySql and JavaDB for now. But nothing prevents me from choosing another database.

Comment: SQL Server includes a diagram editor.  Om pretty sure it is part of the free version.

Comment: The answers that people gave me here were very important. 

What do you mean with "list-of-x" ?

Comment: Try this tool for SQL Server Physical models.

Info can be found here...

https://www.facebook.com/DataModelerTool/

or here...

https://plus.google.com/108968161662966473138

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but effective: [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/).

It has a nice template for ER diagrams complete with relationships, primary key information, etc.  I believe that it can both generate the schema in the database as well as create the diagram by pointing it at a database.

Comment: Nice to know. I did not imagine Microsoft Visio could generate SQL code. I will try when I have the opportunity.

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect. Visio no longer includes this feature.

Answer (score 1):

We've used Case Studio 2 for years to model a fairly complex schema - it's pretty good. We use it to create scripts for MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server. It is now called Toad Data Modeller: https://www.quest.com/products/toad-data-modeler/ There's a freeware version (not sure how this differs from the paid-for licenced version though)

Comment: "The freeware version contains many useful features, however there are some feature restrictions. In majority of cases limits are set for number of objects you can work with (25 entities limit)."

Comment: This is really very nice. The freeware version is good to begin.